# C# 7.0 – Discards and IDisposable out argument

Tags: c#, dispose, c#-7.0

Is Discards feature correctly works with IDisposable objects?

Is it call `Dispose();` when its needed?

---

I have a code:

```
Boolean existing = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name: key, rights: MutexRights.ReadPermissions, result: out Mutex _);
```

Here I need only `existing` variable value.

As you see, I'm trying to use "discard" variable here, but I'm not sure this is correct usage in this case or not.

Because of Mutex obj implements IDisposable.

So which way will be correct in this case? this:

```
Boolean existing = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name: key, rights: MutexRights.ReadPermissions, result: out Mutex _);
```

or this:

```
Mutex mutex; 
Boolean existing = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name: key, rights: MutexRights.ReadPermissions, result: mutex);
mutex.Dispose();
```

Comment: Well, `_.Dispose();` is not wrong, but reviewed behind the [door on the right](https://i2.wp.com/commadot.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wtf.png?w=550).

Comment: I will try `_.Dispose();` code a little bit later, thanks :)

Comment: Do try it, then refactor `_` to `mutex`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created a test application to check @CamilioTerevinto answer.

A simple winforms app with a method:

```
public bool TestMethod(out Image bmp)
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);

    bmp = Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\UKS\Desktop\2000x2000pixels.bmp");

    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    return true;
}
```

Let's try a code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Image img;
    var a = TestMethod(out img);
    img.Dispose();
}
```

[image]

We see an expected behavior -- image was disposed and memory was free.

Let's try next code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var a = TestMethod(out _);
}
```

[image: test 2]

As we see, image wasn't disposed. Memory wasn't free.

## So Discard doesn't call Dispose(); method.

Let's try few more tests:

Construction:

```
var a = TestMethod(out _.Dispose());
```

Will not work. It's tell's that _ doesn't exist in current context.

Contstruction:

```
var a = TestMethod(out _);
_.Dispose();
```

Will do the same result.

So....

## Discards doesn't work properly with IDisposable out argument correctly. You need to call `.Dispose()` explicitly.

Comment: What about something like: using (_ = ZipFile.Open(filename, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) { }
To create an archive if it doesn't exist?

Comment: do the test and write here your results. But even if this will work - this will work by the same way with discard or without discard. Just because of using.

Comment: Yes it does get disposed or you could omit the discard and get same result. I made a question which turned out to be a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67274824/2229933

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand,

```
Boolean existing = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name: key, rights: MutexRights.ReadPermissions, result: out Mutex _);
```

will discard the `Mutex` generated by the call. Discarding it does not mean that some method, like `Dispose()`, will be called.
You need to call `.Dispose()` explicitly.

I'd just continue using

```
Mutex mutex; 
Boolean existing = Mutex.TryOpenExisting(name: key, rights: MutexRights.ReadPermissions, result: mutex);
mutex.Dispose();
```

Comment: I did a check. You're absolutely right. It doesn't dispose objects.Thanks a lot!