# Will the discard variable _ call Dispose() when put in a using statement?

Tags: c#, dispose

I want to create a ZipArchive file if it doesn't already exist. Then I want to open it for reading its information before I update it. So is this valid use of the discard variable _ and does it work as intended?

```
using (_ = ZipFile.Open(filename, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) { }
```

There is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53797089/2229933, he says _ doesn't call dispose when used like this:

```
var a = TestMethod(out _.Dispose());
```

Comment: Did you try it and put a breakpoint to see if it would hit?

Comment: `out _.Dispose()` is invalid syntax. `Dispose` doesn't return a `ref Disposable` (and I'm not sure the language could use that if it did--but I haven't tried it). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59619993) for a better way to dispose a disposable output parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called - check the decompiled [code on sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCAuRBJAIgSwGcAHAewIEMAjAGwFNEBvWRF5JEAFkX2LNoAoAlAwC+zVgmRcAskMbjWEgAz8A+ogC8iAHa0A7miHCFixCcViYF2CKA) (or write a simple [test snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o7Xt1Z)). But if you don't need the variable you can just skip the discard completely and write:

```
using (ZipFile.Open(filename, ZipArchiveMode.Update)) 
{ 

}
```

With the [same effect](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCAuRBJAIgSwGcAHAewIEMAjAGwFNEBvWRF5JEAFkX2LNoAoAlAwC+zVgmRcAskMbjWEgAz8AdrQDuaIcIWLEexWJhHYIoA===).